# Trouble with parsing and evecvp

Tags: c, linux, process, exec

I am trying to write a C program that reads in a Lunix command as a string parses the string into a char*[] and then executes the command using evecvp.

This is my code:

Parsing the string

```
        char *args[40];
        char command[80];
        fgets (command, MAX_LINE, stdin);
        int counter = 0;
        token = strtok(command," ");
        args[0] = token;



        //printf("%s\n",args[0]);

        while(should_run == 1){
            token = strtok(NULL," ");
            if (token == NULL){
                break;
            }
            counter++;
            args[counter] = token; 
            printf("%s\n",token);       
        }
        args[counter+1] = NULL;
        executeCommands(args, counter, -1);
```

Executing the command

```
void executeCommands(char *args[], int counter, int histCounter){
/*int j;
for (j = 0; j <= counter; j++){
    printf("%s",args[j]);
}*/
printf("\n");
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0){
    execvp(args[0], args);
    printf("exec failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
else{
    if(counter == -1 && histCounter == 1){
        wait(NULL);
    }
    else if(*args[counter] == '&'){
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

}

When I give a simple input such as "ls" or "pwd" it outputs "exec failed: No such file or directory." The only command that slightly works is "pwd &" this out puts "ignoring non-option arguments" followed by the correct current path.

Comment: Read carefully [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and your `gdb` debugger. Compile with `gcc -Wall -g`. Study the source code of some free shell (e.g. [GNU bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that the newline character from your input stays at the end of the string, e.g. you're passing `ls\n` to `execvp()` instead of `ls`. Try something like this before calling `executeCommands()`:

```
char *a = args[counter];
a[strlen(a) - 1] = '\0';
args[counter+1] = NULL;
executeCommands(args, counter, -1);
```

Comment: Another quick question which I think is along the same problem. When I enter the command "cd .." or "cd directory" I get "exec failed: no such file or directory" And the directory is most certainly there.